# SQL: Date Difference between two separate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following format:

```
id  |  Date A
----------------
1   |  05/02/12
1   |  05/05/12
1   |  05/08/12
3   |  05/01/12
3   |  05/05/12
3   |  05/06/12
```

Now I'd like to grab the latest (max) date for each id and group by id.
So my SQL output should be:

```
id  |  Date A
----------------
1   |  05/08/12
3   |  05/06/12
```

The dates are not necessarily on order.
Can someone give me a hint on how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: "The dates are not necessarily in order" - since tables have no inherent order, and for any query where order matters, you have to *define* the order that you want, using the available columns, this doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select id, max([Date A]) as 'MaxDate'
from table
group by id
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use Windowing Functions for this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, MAX([Date A]) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS 'Date A'
  FROM table
```

The nice thing about Windowing Functions is that you do not have to GROUP BY things you do not need in the function to get your output results.  They are also really fast.

Here is the BOL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx
Here is some more info on Windowing Functions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(SQL)#Window_function

Comment: This would result in [6 rows in the output](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/525ec/2) which isn't what the OP wants.

Comment: D'oh.  Add in DISTINCT. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/525ec/3